# How to put tkinter Message widget on tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was trying to make a window with tkinter. On the home screen, I would have a label, a few buttons, and then a Message, all on the `tkinter.Canvas`. I created them in different functions, but even then, the label and buttons went on the canvas. The Message didn't, returning an error:

```
  File "C:\Users\bobby\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\NFL Model\nflScreen.py", line 54, in homeScreen
    self.homeText = tk.Message(master=self.canvas, text=self.getText(0), width=550)
  File "C:\Users\bobby\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2816, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'message', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\bobby\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2139, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".59508144.59508176"
```

Here is my code to make the window:

```
import tkinter as tk

    class Window(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, master=None):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
            self.pack()
            self.makeScroll(); self.showMenu(); self.homeScreen(); 

        def makeScroll(self):
            self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='#F0F0F0', width=1000, height=600)
            self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0) ###Makes the Canvas. This part works well

        def showMenu(self):
            self.home = tk.Button(self.canvas, text="Home", command=self.homeScreen, width=10)
            self.home.grid(column=0, row=1) ###Make some buttons, this part works well. 

            self.rank = tk.Button(self.canvas, text="Rankings", command=self.rankingScreen, width=10)
            self.rank.grid(column=1, row=1)

            ###I tried adding a Message here to the canvas, and it worked, but I need the message to be made in another function

        def homeScreen(self):
            ###This part doesn't work. I know that self.canvas is still a variable. 
            self.homeText = tk.Message(master=self.canvas, text=self.getText(0), width=550)
            self.homeText.grid(column=0, row=3, columnspan=7)
```

Basically, I create the `tkinter.Canvas` in `makeScroll()`. When I add widgets to it in `showMenu()`, that works. But when I try to add widgets in `homeScreen()`, it doesn't. Does anyone know why, and how to fix it?

Comment: I suspect that in your actual code, you're calling `self.homeScreen()` at an inappropriate time - after a call to `.mainloop()`, perhaps, at which point the window no longer exists to add widgets to.  Also, why are you adding everything to a Canvas, rather than directly to the Frame?  The normal reason for doing that is to allow the contents to be scrolled, but you aren't doing things right for that - in particular, you have to use `<canvas>.create_window()` rather than `<widget>.grid()` to place the widgets under control of the Canvas.

Comment: I did want to add a scrollbar, so I added everything to the Canvas. I called `self.homeScreen` in `Window.__init__()`, and I called `.mainloop()` after initializing, so I think it should do this before `.mainloop()`.

Comment: I also started by putting everything in a Frame, then realized I needed a scrollbar, so I changed everything to a Canvas. In the frame I did `<widget>.grid()`, so to keep the same structure I did `<widget>.grid()` with the Canvas.

Comment: @B.Johnson: ***"How to put tk.Message on tkinter Canvas"***: To places a Tkinter widget on the canvas, you have to use [Canvas.create_window-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method).

Comment: @B.Johnson: ***"The Message didn't, returning an error:"***: This is the `Error` from `tk.Message`: `.TclError: bad window path name`

Comment: @B.Johnson: ***"When I add widgets to it in showMenu(), that works."***: Your example does not work, I get: `.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid`. Fixing this, it works for me. Still don't get what you trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to add the Message widget to the Canvas. For me, I had the two buttons on the screen, but got an error when I tried putting the Message widget on it.

Comment: The code you posted does not give the error you say it does.

Comment: @B.Johnson: ***"got an error when putting `tk.Message` on it."***: Make a [mcve] so we can prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out after a while that this was just a logic error. In my real code, I called a function that would delete the canvas object at the start of the homeScreen() function.